# subset topk values of a pytorch tensor greater than threshold

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 2d tensor, How can i get top 10 row wise subset of **values** and **indices** if  value **greater than threshold**

```
tensor_3x100 = torch.rand(3, 100)
top_ = torch.topk(tensor_3x100, 10)

top_.gt(0.95)
```

I can get top 10 row wise elements using `topk`, But for me

1. some times not all of top 10 row values will be greater than threshold.
2. if none of the row values are greater that threshold select the highest one

Please help.

Comment: When performing row-wise logic on you will end up with differing numbers of elements on one of the dimensions based on the threshold. This is not possible, all rows must have the exact same number of elements.

Comment: Do i have to iterate , to extract differing number of elements?

Comment: Indeed, Pytorch works only with homogenous data.